# Custom NPM Package installing issue

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2

I made a custom npm package which I'm trying to install in my Vue application. I tried to follow some tutorials and steps but I'm getting an error below:

> This dependency was not found:
>
> - chatinterfaceui in ./src/main.js
>
> To install it, you can run: npm install --save chatinterfaceui

### My main.js file in my chatinterfaceui lib is:

```js
import ChatUi from './ChatUi.vue'

export default {
    install (Vue, options) {
      if (!options || !options.store) {
        throw new Error('Please initialise plugin.');
      }
   
      Vue.component('chat-ui', ChatUi);
    }
  }
```

### The package.json file for the chatinterfaceui lib:

```json
{
  "name": "chatinterfaceui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "build-bundle": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name chatinterfaceui ./src/ChatUi.vue",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "main": "./dist/chatinterfaceui.common.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "autolinker": "^3.14.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "emoji-js": "^3.5.0",
    "escape-goat": "^3.0.0",
    "msgdown": "^1.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.3.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {
      "vue/no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

### My main.js file for the Vue application is:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import ChatUi from 'chatinterfaceui'

Vue.use(ChatUi)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

### My package.js is:

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "chatinterfaceui": "^0.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "dialogflow": "^1.2.0",
    "uuid": "^8.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-beautiful-chat": "^2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.3.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

In my main Vue application in which I want to use my library, when I try to use the library, I'm getting the warning. I feel I'm doing something silly, but can't understand or find what.

Comment: What is the `package.json` for your `chatinterfaceui` library? Have you defined the `main` or `module` properties?

Comment: Hi Phil, I've added the package.json file where I have my main.js property. I was reading that I could bundle up the lib and use the common.js file from the dist folder as my main property. I'm sure I must have done this wrong?